# Как правильно добавить ивент onclick в sugarcrm?

Tags: php, javascript

Я тут разбираюсь с SugarCRM, и немного завтрял на задании добавить логики на фронтэнд, а точнее нужно добавить событие onclick на элемент. Где происходит бинд ивентов и как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь попробовать так

html:

```
example1:
<input value="Нажми меня" onclick="alert('Клик!')" type="button">

example2:

<somelement id='element' onclick='demostration(this)'>Some text</somelement>

<script>
    function demostration(element){
         alert('Click fired uraaaa !!!!');
         console.log(element);
    }
    //Ну или так

    var element = document.getElementById('element');

    element.addEventListener( "click" , function() {
        alert('Спасибо!');
    });
</script>
```

https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но мне бы тыкнули хотябы в какой файл эти изменения вносить....

Comment: Смотри тут  https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2013/02/20/adding-custom-code-or-html-to-a-module-view/